# Formula containing Sum and If statements

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please help - I need a formula which says if D9 has a value, then the sum of E9 will be C9*D9, other the sum will be C9

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the `IF` and the `ISBLANK` functions. Like this:

```
IF(ISBLANK(D9),C9,C9*D9)
```

Analizing:

1. `IF` has 3 params: `IF(a,b,c)`.

   - `a` is the expression you want to evaluate for `true` or `false`.
   - `b` is what is the expression to evaluate if `a` is `true`.
   - `c` is the expression if `a` is `false`.
2. In this case, you evaluate wether or not `D9` *is blank*.
3. Since it evaluates to `true` if it **doesn't** have a value, you have to switch your params: `b` is when you don't have a value and `c` when it has one.

Comment: The formula above will fail if D9 is a non-numeric value and the resulting multiplication will show `#Value`  Instead of `ISBLANK` try `IF(CELL("type",D9)="v", C9*D9, C9)`